# Is it possible watch the caret position in a textarea without polling?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I would like a callback function to be executed each time the caret or selection moves in the text area.
Anybody knows how to do that?

**Edit**: I know how to retrieve the carret position. I'm interested in how to watch for the change. With my current knowledge i would test carret position on each **keyup** / **mousemouve** / **mouseup**. Is there a smarter (and more performant) way to do it. Are there event that may change the carret position that i did not think about ?

Comment: How about onKeyPress and onClick?

Comment: It would be onkeydown! Because if he wants to override the basic functionality (like inserting 4 spaces when tab is pressed) he needs to do it before the keyup or keypress events.

Comment: The solution depends on what the OP wants to do in his callback function, but in general, the "keydown" and "textinput" events (the latter one for cutting/pasting with the "Cut"/"Paste" context menu items selected with a mouse) are his friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I finally found after exploring each of possible solutions that there is no performant way to do that for large amounts of text.

I have no other solution than waiting for my web application to meet the technical requirements to use a modern text area replacement library (= not depending of ie quirks mode).

Answer (score 2):

There's a DOM event onSelect that you can use, but it will only pick up caret movements when that movement affects the selection. Here's a JSBin with a demo:

http://jsbin.com/eyaril/4/edit

Just select text in the box and view the output in firebug.

Comment: I did not know this event. Thanks for the tip event if it's only a part of the solution